# Qt Mobile(Android / IOS) Process Background

Tags: android, ios, qt, qml

I want to know if the device reload the background process if it's kill by the device himself ?

And if anyone know where i can learn about the background process for Qt mobile app please ?

I know that a Service in Android Studio can do that.

Comment: There are no background processes in iOS as such. There are specific background modes that are available to apps these are described in the iOS app programming guide

Comment: on Qt-Android, in AndroidManifest.xml, you need to set `<meta-data android:name="android.app.background_running" android:value="false"/>` to `true`

Comment: Thank you for the answers, i will try that